# Create custom rule for code analysis using sonar for C# project

Tags: .net, sonarqube

I have jdk version 1.5.0 and fxcop 1.36 version... My system is 32 bit and windows 7 operating system..  I want to install and cofigure the sonar into my system.. What are the steps to be followed to install and how to create a custom rule in sonar for my application?

If any one knows please help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Everything is perfectly described in the Sonar wiki, please take time to read the documentation before asking such general questions:

- How to install Sonar: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade

  - Please note the [requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements): you must at least use Java 6
- How to set up the C# ecosystem: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Guide

  - Please install a newer version of FxCop, 1.36 is really really old...